# Parsing data from url - Localhost vs Server

Tags: php, parsing, request, localhost, html-parsing

I want to download entire page using this function, which I get from `stackoverflow`

```
public function get_remote_data($url, $post_paramtrs = false) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if ($post_paramtrs) {
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=bla&" . $post_paramtrs);
    } curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'CookieName1=Value;');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    $follow_allowed = ( ini_get('open_basedir') || ini_get('safe_mode')) ? false : true;
    if ($follow_allowed) {
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    }curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 9);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    $data = curl_exec($c);
    $status = curl_getinfo($c);
    curl_close($c);
    preg_match('/(http(|s)):\/\/(.*?)\/(.*\/|)/si', $status['url'], $link);
    $data = preg_replace('/(src|href|action)=(\'|\")((?!(http|https|javascript:|\/\/|\/)).*?)(\'|\")/si', '$1=$2' . $link[0] . '$3$4$5', $data);
    $data = preg_replace('/(src|href|action)=(\'|\")((?!(http|https|javascript:|\/\/)).*?)(\'|\")/si', '$1=$2' . $link[1] . '://' . $link[3] . '$3$4$5', $data);
    if ($status['http_code'] == 200) {
        return $data;
    } elseif ($status['http_code'] == 301 || $status['http_code'] == 302) {
        if (!$follow_allowed) {
            if (empty($redirURL)) {
                if (!empty($status['redirect_url'])) {
                    $redirURL = $status['redirect_url'];
                }
            } if (empty($redirURL)) {
                preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)(\r|\n)/si', $data, $m);
                if (!empty($m[2])) {
                    $redirURL = $m[2];
                }
            } if (empty($redirURL)) {
                preg_match('/href\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)here\<\/a\>/si', $data, $m);
                if (!empty($m[1])) {
                    $redirURL = $m[1];
                }
            } if (!empty($redirURL)) {
                $t = debug_backtrace();
                return call_user_func($t[0]["function"], trim($redirURL), $post_paramtrs);
            }
        }
    } return "ERRORCODE22 with $url!!<br/>Last status codes<b/>:" . json_encode($status) . "<br/><br/>Last data got<br/>:$data";
}
```

Then I manipulate with this data, but it is not the point. I'm working on Localhost, and it works fine. But when I deloyed my app to server, I'm getting different results.

Basically, that function above returns different results depending where I use it - localhost or web server. For example, on **localhost** function returns html with 163 lines of code, however on **web server** only 74 lines.

**P.S.** app is very small, only 1 `.php` file and it is identical on localhost and web server.

What can be possible reason that script on localhost returning different data then from server?

Comment: For example have these parameters: `ini_get('open_basedir')` and `ini_get('safe_mode')` the same setup on local maschine and on server?

Comment: Do you use the same url and `$post_paramtrs` in your requests? Is it the same PHP-version? The same PHP-config? If you look at the response, what is missing/what is extra between the responses? Some sites/services can return different content depending on the location of the client (in your case, where your computer is vs. where the server is located).

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I don't really have access to apache configuration on server. But what these lines should do?

Comment: They are changing the flow of the code that comes after `$follow_allowed = ( ini_get('open_basedir') || ini_get('safe_mode')) ? false : true;`  Check if `$follow_allowed` is true/false  on both maschines. If there are different, then you know why you have diffrent results.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for reply, I don't actually use ``$post_paramtrs``, php version is different, on localhost it is php 7, on server 5.6; PHP-config - what should I look  there for?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions , actually it both true on local and server